# Java: Marshalling Object -- Removing extra ns2 annotation in xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, xml-namespaces

I am trying to marshall data within an object into an xml file based on a defined schema. However when I print out the xml file, I recieve extra annotations on the xml tags. Is there any way to get rid of the extra namespace annotation (i.e. ns2)

This is an example of the xml I receive from marshalling.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes">
<root xmlns:ns2="http://www.something.com/something">
    <ns2:food>steak</ns2:food>
    <ns2:beverage>water</ns2:beverage>
</root>
```

What I want is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes">
<root xmlns="http://www.something.com/something">
    <food>steak</food>
    <beverage>water</beverage>
</root>
```

This is what my Java code is doing:

```
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.schema");
            JAXBElement<FoodSchema> element = new JAXBElement<FoodSchema>
                (new QName("FoodSchema"), Food.class, foodSchema);
            Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(object.getFilePath());
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); 
            marshaller.marshal(element, os);
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I was able to do this with xslt described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033285/remove-namespace-from-xml-in-java

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By adding a namespace URI ("http://www.something.com/something") to the `QName` used to construct the JAXB element, and leveraging the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation will get you the namespace qualification that you are looking for:

**package-info**

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="http://www.something.com/something", 
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package forum7014746;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Food**

```
package forum7014746;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Food {

    private String food;
    private String beverage;

    public String getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public void setFood(String food) {
        this.food = food;
    }

    public String getBeverage() {
        return beverage;
    }

    public void setBeverage(String beverage) {
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum7014746;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Food.class);

        Food foodSchema = new Food();
        foodSchema.setFood("steak");
        foodSchema.setBeverage("water");

        JAXBElement<Food> element = new JAXBElement<Food> (new QName("http://www.something.com/something","FoodSchema"), Food.class, foodSchema);

        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(element, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FoodSchema xmlns="http://www.something.com/something">
    <beverage>water</beverage>
    <food>steak</food>
</FoodSchema>
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't have to add the package info annotation tag in order for it to work. Adding the extra schema namespace location in the QName was enough. Thanks again!

Comment: This helped me, I was sending a different URI than the defined in the schema and it was causing the resultXMLstring to have another namespace

Answer (score 5):

add to xsd schema definition **elementFormDefault** and **attributeFormDefault**:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ...
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" ... >
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for answer. Just to give sample code 
before:

```
 marshaller.marshal(new  JAXBElement(new QName(**""**,"Document"),Document.class,swiftDoc), sw);
```

after:

```
marshaller.marshal(new  JAXBElement(new QName(**"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema**","Document"),Document.class,swiftDoc), sw);
```

and extra "ns:" was removed.