# Marshal/unmarshal when there are 2 XmlRootElements from 2 xsd files

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

Something tells me I'm performing a Java horror show with xsd to class generation via JAXB... Hopefully someone can tell me what!

I've been provided with several related XSD's, which I need to be able to interact with an API. Let's say there is A.xsd and B.xsd. A.xsd defines a body element that can essentially contain a list of any type, including B objects:

```
<xsd:element name="Body" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xsd:sequence>
<xsd:anyAttribute namespace="##any"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

So I generate the classes for A.xsd, whose root element is tagged like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "A", namespace = "http://www.example.com/a")
public class A {
```

And I create `package-info.java` in the same package to have that namespace so I can marshal it:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.example.com/a", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.mypackage;
```

Now I generate the classes for B.xsd into the **same package**. (I renamed the A's `ObjectFactory` to something else because IntelliJ doesn't append the factory).

(**EDIT**: I had also created them in different packages but then I get marshalling issues because the request xml needs both A and B.)

(Sub-question - is this the way you would ordinarily do it?)

So the B class now has:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "B")
public class B {
```

With this I can now create an A, and marshal it. I don't get nasty ns2's when I embed B's in the body thanks to the `package-info.java` (a la [Java: Marshalling Object -- Removing extra ns2 annotation in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014746/java-marshalling-object-removing-extra-ns2-annotation-in-xml)).

The response message I get from the API also gives me an A, which I can unmarshal without an issue. **BUT** the underlying object in the Body, which should be a `B` will not get unmarshalled - it is a Node object, so I tried:

```
JAXBContext specialContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(B.class);
Object companyAppt = specialContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal((Node)reply.getBody().getAny().get(0));
```

But I get this exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"/some/uri/location", local:"B"). Expected elements are <{http://www.example.com/a}B>
```

Therefore I think the answer lies in that `package-info.java` but I just don't know how to manipulate it.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Here's the xsd's i'm working with:

"A" in my example = http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/Egov_ch-v2-0.xsd

"B" in my exmaple = http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/CompanyDetails-v2-1.xsd

Other dependant xds: http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/chbase-v2-1.xsd

Comment: can you pls add chbase-v2-1.xsd

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create the Jaxb classes using xjc where you can pass multiple xsds and use a bindings file if there is conflict.

xjc -d out  A.xsd B.xsd

Comment: Thanks, tried that but it gives me lots of `[com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions` exceptions, but inconveniently doesn't tell me where! Hence xjc one at a time.

Comment: can you post your xsds here. Did you try generating using eclipse. we did it before.

Comment: Edited the post to have the xsd's. I'm sure Eclipse works great, I'm using intellij which is just using the xjc jar i think

Comment: by the way generating the classes isn't the issue - I've generated them fine and would rather not modify them as its an external API. Its the unmarshalling i'm having an issue with.

Comment: Unmarshalling happens based on the JAXB classes and if the JAXB classes are not right it would not set all the properties.

Comment: can you pls add chbase-v2-1.xsd you are missing it.

Comment: Can you create the jaxb classes in two seperate packages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57111/discussion-between-user2393012-and-surendra-poranki).

Comment: @ManishPatel Did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue?

Comment: @dweeb no sorry